# The patterns of possibility for nontrivial automorphisms and nontrivial elementary embeddings of the universe

Tags: set-theory, forcing, axiom-of-choice

In their paper "The Role of the Foundation Axiom in the Kunen Inconsistency" ([arXiv:1311.0814](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0814) [Math.LO]), Daghighi, Golshani, Hamkins, and Jerabek show that the patterns of possibility for the existence of nontrivial automorphisms and nontrivial elementary embeddings of the universe in models of set theory without Foundation take the following form:

{$id_{V}$}$\subseteq$$Aut(V)$$\subseteq$$Eem(V)$

where $id_{V}$ is just the identity mapping from $V$ to $V$, $Aut(V)$ are the automorphisms from $V$ to $V$,and $Eem(V)$ are the elementary embeddings from $V$ to $V$.

In fact, they prove that there are models of $ZFC^{-f}$ that realize each of these four separating refinements of {$id_{V}$}$\subseteq$$Aut(V)$$\subseteq$$Eem(V)$:

i).  {$id_{V}$}=$Aut(V)$=$Eem(V)$

ii). {$id_{V}$}$\subsetneq$$Aut(V)$=$Eem(V)$

iii).{$id_{V}$}=$Aut(V)$$\subsetneq$$Eem(V)$

iv). {$id_{V}$}$\subsetneq$$Aut(V)$$\subsetneq$$Eem(V)$

My question is simply this:

Are there models of $NGB+{\lnot}AC$ that realize each of the four separating refinements?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Why is this question deemed 'unhelpful'? What, if anything, is wrong with this question?

Comment: Did you intentionally drop the superscript, so that you are requiring foundation? Then (ii) and (iv) are impossible, the straightforward proof by $\in$-induction that every automorphism is the identity does not need any choice. (i) is easy (e.g., take a symmetric extension violating choice of a model of V=L with no inaccessible cardinals), and (iii) is a restatement of the open problem whether the existence of Reinhardt cardinals is consistent.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  Yes, I did intentionally drop the superscript.  My purpose in doing so was to see if $NGB+{\lnot}AC+{\lnot}RR$ was Consistent.  If you are correct in determining that (ii) and (iv) are impossible, then what of Prof. Hamkins' contention that his and Palumbo's model (see Thm. 5) that shows that $ZF+{\lnot}RR$ is consistent if $ZF$ is translates into a model of $NGB+{\lnot}AC+{\lnot}RR$?  Such a model would, by definition of ${\lnot}RR$, seemingly have to realize either (ii) or (iv)--so which does it satisfy (please enlighten me)?  Also, Yair's answer to my previous question

Comment: (cont.) that is, that $NGB+{\lnot}AC$+"There exists a Reinhardt cardinal" is equiconsistent with  $NGB+{\lnot}AC+$"There exists a Reinhardt cardinal"+${\lnot}RR$ would have to go by the boards as well because such a model would seemingly have to satisfy (ii) or (iv) as well.

Comment: What is RR, what is Joel and Palumbo’s model, and what is Theorem 5?

Comment: Oh, I found the definition. I fail to see the connection of RR to automorphisms of the universe, which is a proper class. In any case, the fact that (assuming foundation) the universe has no automorphisms is completely trivial: $j(x)=\{j(y):y\in x\}=\{y:y\in x\}=x$, where the first equality comes from $j$ being an automorphism, and the second equality is the $\in$-induction hypothesis.

Comment: Note that ZF proves that there are plenty of rigid binary relations on various sets, such as $(\alpha,<)$ for ordinals $\alpha$, or indeed $(t,\in)$ for any transitive set $t$. What it doesn’t prove that there are such relations on *arbitrary* base sets.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  Then what of Yair Hayut's (now alleged) equiconsistency result which was his answer to my mathoverflow question "The role of the rigid relation (RR) principle in the Kunen inconsistency". As I stated in my previous comment to you, he seems to have proven that, assuming $NGB+{\lnot}AC+$"There exists a Reinhardt cardinal" is consistent, then $NGB+{\lnot}AC+$"There exists a Reinhardt cardinal"+${\lnot}RR$ is also consistent which means that either (ii) or (iv) holds (so you might want to check out his answer).  What you are suggesting, then, is that $RR$ plays no part in

Comment: (cont.)in the proof of the Kunen inconsistency.  That's fine, but if you find any unpatchable holes in Yair's argument, would you be willing to post your comments as an answer to my previous question? I would definitely accept it (provided you can show that the model constructed as the proof of Thm. 5 in the Hamkins-Palumbo paper cannot be extended to form a nontrivial automorphism of the universe)

Comment: I don’t see what any of what you are saying has any bearing on the question you asked here. I read your other question about RR, and the answers, and no automorphisms of $V$ are mentioned anywhere. RR says that for every set $a$, there exists a relation $r$ such that $(a,r)$ is rigid. The impossibility of (ii) and (iv) says that $(V,\in)$ is rigid. There is no connection between the two. You seem to be confused about something basic.

Comment: In particular, in the various comments above you keep claiming “Such a model would, by definition of $¬RR$, seemingly have to realize either (ii) or (iv)”, “such a model would seemingly have to satisfy (ii) or (iv)”, and “...which means that either (ii) or (iv) holds”. All these are non sequitur.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: How then do interpret Yair's answer to me?  Also, in my question, I mentioned (regarding $NGB+{\lnot}AC$) that $RR$ was to be "appropriately defined" for $NGB$, by which I meant that $RR$ should be allowed to hold for classes in $NGB$ (if you believe I am confusing sets with classes).

Comment: If you extend RR to classes, it only makes $\neg RR$ *weaker*. It says that there exists a class $A$ such that for every relation $R$, $(A,R)$ is not rigid. This does not in any way contradict the fact that there is a different class, namely $V$, which does carry a rigid relation. Yair’s answer says what it says: if it is consistent with NBG that there is a nontrivial elementary embedding $V\to V$, then the existence of such an elementary embedding is also consistent with there being a set that does not carry a rigid relation.

Comment: @EmilJerabek:  If we assume the existence of nonstandard (nonwellfounded) ordinals in models of $ZF$ (as does Cohen in his paper "Automorphisms of Set Theory"), can there exist nontrivial automorphisms of the universe and/or Reinhardt cardinals in such models?

Comment: I have no access to the paper, however, as far as I can gather from Google books preview, he is talking about *external* automorphisms of the model for which replacement needn’t hold. This is a whole different game. *Every* first-order model has elementary extensions with lots of such automorphisms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's some confusion over automorphisms/embeddings which are "internal" vs. those which are "external." Some comments which I hope clear things up:

- No model of ZF has nontrivial definable (even from parameters) automorphisms. This is a proof by transfinite induction: let $\alpha$ be least such that some element of $V_\alpha$ is moved by the automorphism $A$. This $\alpha$ exists by Foundation and the definability of $A$ (this is where the argument breaks down if $A$ isn't definable - but note that it also suffices for our model to be well-founded!). Clearly $\alpha>0$, but then let $x\in V_\alpha$ be moved by $A$. Since $\alpha>0$, $x\not=\emptyset$, but for each $y\in x$ we have $A(y)=y$. So $A(x)\not=\{A(y): y\in x\}$, which means $A$ is not an automorphism.
- On the other hand, there are models of ZF with automorphisms. This is just a fact of logic: if $T$ is any first-order theory with an infinite model, then $T$ has a model whose automorphism group is nontrivial. The proof is a nice combination of compactness and Ramsey's theorem for pairs; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Mostowski_theorem.
- This means: **as long as we talk about automorphisms of models of ZF, we mean *external* automorphisms.** The same goes for similar set theories. Note that the crucial axiom is **Foundation**, which means that theories without foundation - e.g., $ZF^{-f}$ or $NF$ - may have definable automorphisms.
- However, this sort of argument doesn't let us build automorphisms with prescribed properties. For instance, if we want a model of a theory $T$ which has a nontrivial automorphism of *finite order*, we might be out of luck! In particular, if any model of $T$ has a definable linear ordering, then **no** model of $T$ has a nontrivial automorphism of finite order! This is a good exercise.
- A harder exercise is to show that no model of ZFC (well-founded or not) has a nontrivial automorphism of finite order; this is due to Friedman, and is quoted at the beginning of Cohen's paper. Note that this means that if we can build a model of ZF with a nontrivial automorphism of finite order, as Cohen does, that model must satisfy $\neg AC$.

---

To answer your question: if by automorphism/embedding we mean **definable** automorphism/embedding, then: with the axiom of foundation in hand, options 2 and 4 are immediately ruled out; and option 1 is achieved in e.g. any symmetric submodel of a set-generic extension of a model of $V=L$. Meanwhile, any instance of 3 would contain a Reinhardt cardinal, so it's generally believed that 3 can't happen.