# Can there exist such a sequence of elementary embeddings of the universe to itself?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, embeddings

Working in ZfC + [Wholeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wholeness_axiom):

Can we have a countable sequence of non-trivial elementary embeddings of the universe to itself, such that the range of each embedding is a subclass of the range of its successor, and such that the union of all the ranges of those embeddings is the universe itself?

Formally can we have a proper class sequence $j`\mathbb N$ such that:

$\forall n \in \mathbb N : j_n: V \prec V \land rng(j_{n+1}) \supset rng(j_n) \\ \forall x \exists n \in \mathbb N : x \in rng(j_n)$

Where $\mathbb N$ is the set of all finite von Neumann ordinals.

Note: ZfC means ZFC but with replacement restricted to the pure language of set theory, i.e. it doesn't use the symbol $j$; however, $j$ is allowed in all instances of separation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was pointed out by Monroe that if $\lambda$ is a limit and $j:V_\lambda\to V_\lambda$ is elementary and $j_n$ is the $n$th iterate, i.e. $j_0=j$ and $j_{n+1}=j_n(j_n)$, and $\kappa_n=\mathrm{crit}(j_n)$, then since $\lim_{n<\omega}\kappa_n=\lambda$,  we get every $x\in V_\lambda$ is in $\mathrm{rng}(j_n)$ for some $n<\omega$.

Given this, we can arrange the increasing range condition as follows.
Choose a strictly increasing sequence $\left<n_i\right>_{i<\omega}$
such that for each $\alpha<\lambda$ there is $i<\omega$ such that $j_{n_{i-1}}\circ j_{n_{i-2}}\circ\ldots\circ j_{n_0}(\alpha)<\mathrm{crit}(j_{n_i})$. (Just construct the sequence recursively on $i$, and at stage $i$, make it work for $\alpha=\kappa_i$.) Now define $k_i:V_\lambda\to V_\lambda$ as the direct limit
\begin{equation}\ldots \circ j_{n_{i+2}}\circ j_{n_{i+1}}\circ j_{n_i},\end{equation}
i.e. for each $x\in V_\lambda$ set $k_i(x)=$ the common value of
\begin{equation}j_{n_{i+\ell}}\circ j_{n_{i+\ell-1}}\circ\ldots\circ j_{n_i}(x)\end{equation}
for large $\ell<\omega$, noting that by the choice of the $n_i$'s, for every $x\in V_\lambda$, $k_i(x)\in V_\lambda$ is well-defined; and $k_i$ is easily elementary. Note that $k_{i}=k_{i+1}\circ j_{n_i}$, and therefore $\mathrm{rng}(k_i)\subseteq\mathrm{rng}(k_{i+1})$. And note $\lim_{i<\omega}\mathrm{crit}(k_i)=\lambda$. So we get the desired conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I have one simple concern, can $\omega$ be the standard set of naturals? Or it must be non-standard? I mean if we can get that sequence and $\omega$ is standard, can this make us prove by compactness the existence of an automorphism over $V$ which is inconsistent with ZfC.

Comment: It can be standard; starting with ZFC + $I_3$, take a sequence $\left<k_n\right>_{n<\omega}$ as above, and then consider the model $(V_\lambda,\left<k_n\right>_{n<\omega})$, which models (adapting your notation above) ZfC + ``$\omega$-wholeness'', meaning that we have a single predicate for the sequence, and it can be used in Separation (but Collection only for $\in$-formulas). What sort of automorphism do you mean?

Comment: I just though if this is true, then we can define a theory stipulating the existence of an embedding $F$ from $V$ to $V$ such that the range of each $j_n$ is a subclass of the range of $F$, I mean each $n^{th}$ axiom say that the range of  $j_n$ is a subclass of the range of $ F$, since for each finite steps we have a consistent theory, then the whole theory is consistent by compactness, but $F$ would be an automorphism. But this is inconsistent. While if $\omega$ is non-standard, then compactness won't work, and there will be no problem.

Comment: I mean automorphism on membership.

Comment: @Zuhair I do not see why $\operatorname{ran} j_n\subseteq\operatorname{ran}F$ is relevant to your compactness argument. Did you mean applying the compactness theorem over the elementary diagram of $V$, with axioms for $F$?

Comment: @HanulJeon, its relevant because the range of $F$ would be $V$, and thus $F$ would be an automorphism, and by the way I meant $F$ to be non-trivial. The idea is to have a theory with $F$ being primitive, and stipulate that $F$ is a non-trivial elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$, now we add an $n$-axiom stating that the range of $j_n$ is a subclass of $F$, and the whole theory would be consistent by compactness, but by then $F$ would be an automorphism from $V$ to $V$, which is contradictory, so $\omega$ must be non-standard.

Comment: @Zuhair Whatever you mean, the model that is given by compactness need not be the same with the previous $V$, and [every first-order theory with an infinite model has a model with a non-trivial automorphism](https://mathoverflow.net/a/221250/48041). (Especially, the new model given by the compactness theorem may fall into that case.) The new model may have the nonstandard $\omega$, but I do not think $\omega$ in the original model must be non-standard.

Comment: @HanulJeon, well $F$ is not external, it is used in instances of separation, (and that's enough against automorphism ) and $V$ is the same $V$ of course, and $\omega$ is the one in the original model. Thus I think if my argument is correct, then $\omega$ in that case must be non-standard, and I mean $\omega$ in the original model of course. The reference you've given is about *external* automorphisms.

Comment: @Zuhair How can you be sure that the compactness theorem provides the same $V$ as you previously used? I am not even sure that you can apply the compactness theorem for *class* models internally.

Comment: @HanulJeon, $V$ here just denotes the universe of all sets of the theory, now we have every set belonging to the range of some $j_n$, and also we have the range of every $j_n$ being a subclass of the range of $F$, then every set belongs to the range of $F$ and since $F$ is axiomatized to be an embedding from the unvierse to itself, then $F$ would be an automorphism, and since $F$ can be used in separation, then this would give the inconsistency. Of course if $\omega$ [i.e. the set of all natural indices of the $j_n$'s] is non-standard, then compactness won't work, and there will be no problem.

Comment: @HanulJeon, by the way $V$ as a symbol is not necessarily among the signature of our theory, although we can add it, and enforce matters to be as such.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I don't understand your compactness idea, since the $j_n$'s do not agree with each other.  You can't combine them into one function $F$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, we fool the system by letting $F$ having the range of every $j_n$ as a subclass of it. At each $n$-axiom the system would think that $F$ is simply $j_n$, so the theory down to each $n$-axiom is consistent, now by compactness the theory with all $n$-axioms would be consistent, we could make this axiomatization because we assumed $\omega$ as the standard $\mathbb N$. But this is contradictory since $F$ would be an *internal* automorphism from the universe to itself, which cannot be! So $\omega$ must be non-standard. Now, I might be wrong of course, but I don't see where this fails?

Comment: @Zuhair Compactness requires that every finite set of sentences is jointly consistent, not just each one separately.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, yes they will be, every finite set of sentences would be interpreted by the theory down to each $j_n$, that is $F$ would be just that $j_n$, I'm speaking about the every finite set of sentences of that theory, not just the individual axioms.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar It sounds like the axioms include (or imply) "$F = j_n$" for each $n$.  This is not consistent since $j_n \not= j_{n+1}$.  They are terms for functions with different critical points.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, No! up to each $n$-axiom $F$ be *interpreted* by the respective $j_n$. The finite set of axioms are either finite set of axioms of the original theory which are consistent of course, or they include a finite set of $n$-axioms (those saying that the range of $F$ is a superset of the range of $j_n$), and those can be *interpreted* as taking $F$ to be the $j_n$ for maximal $n$ in those axioms, so its consistent also.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Oh I see, sorry.  Yes so in this collection of interpretations you would also have the sentence “F is not surjective” coming up each time.  So the model produced by compactness is certainly nonstandard, and it is not a model of an automorphism of $V$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, suppose $x \not \in rng(F)$, by axiom about the $j_n$'s there must exist a natural $n$ such that $x \in rng(j_n)$, fix such an $n$, since $n$ is assumed to be standard, then take the corresponding $n$-axiom which states that $rng(j_n) \subset rng(F)$, then $x \in rng(F)$ a contradiction. So all sets are in $rng(F)$, thus $F$ is an automorphism. Notice that the statement "F is not surjective" is  not axiomatized, so it is not part of the sentences we want to prove by compactness. This shows that $\mathbb N$ cannot be the standard one.

Comment: If $\mathbb N$ in the proof above (written as $\omega$) is non standard, then compactness wont apply, and there is no problem.

Comment: As Monroe mentioned, ``$F$ is not surjective'' seems to be in the theory, so $F$ isn't an automorphism. If you construct a model $W$ via compactness satisfying some reasonable finite fragment of the theory of the model $(V,\left<k_n\right>_{n<\omega})$ costructed above (which was wellfounded), together with...

Comment: ...the statements ``$F:V\to V$ is elementary and non-identity and $\mathrm{range}(k_n)\subseteq\mathrm{range}(F)$'', for each $n$, including separation for $F$ and the sequence of $k$'s, then $W$ will have nonstandard $\omega$, and the interpretation $F^W$ of $F$ could just be $k^W_a$ for one of the nonstandard integers $a$ of $W$.

Comment: @FarmerS, I agree with what you said. But, that was not what I'm speaking about. It appears that my flow was in thinking that for each $x$ I can *pick* a  natural $n$ with an axiom such that $x \in rng(j_n) \subset rng(F)$  (by assuming that $n$ is standard) and so $x \in rng(F)$, this will make $F$ an automorphism, but it seems that picking of axioms by assumption of the naturals being standard doesn't work in proofs.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar The problem is that, although all standard x will get into the range of F, some new nonstandard sets will appear outside the range.  You can add the sentence “F is surjective” to the collection, but what is the interpretation for the finite fragments then?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, thanks for the clarification, I think I know what's happening now. Bringing F embedding into the picture, caused having nonstandard naturals $n*$'s and together with them comes new embeddings $j_{n^*}$'s, now the condition of every set belong to a range of a $j_n$ wouldn't distinquish the naturally indexed $j$'s from those nonstandardly indexed, so although the range of every  $j_n$ for a standard $n$ is contained in the range of F,still there are other $j_{n^*}$ (nonstanardly indexed) whose ranges contain sets that are not in any $j_n$ for a standard n, and so outside of range F

Comment: cont... so in the new theory (that resulted from compactness) the range of F doesn't contain all sets, and so the set of naturals in that model of the new theory is not the same as in the original one. Hanul Jeon was right then, $V$ and $\omega$ did change as a result of compactness. So, still in the new model there is a countable sequence satisfying all conditions above, but this contains some non-standards, but that doesn't affect the original model having all of its naturals being standard. Thanks.